# How to change color of the text in visible cell of tableview in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

On Pressing the pen button i can change the color of the theme as u can see.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Now i want to change the text inside the visible cells to look like rest of the things color.
How can i change the color of the text of a visible cell.

Comment: What did you try? add some code, What difficulty in that and what excelity you want to do?

Comment: what end result do you actually want?

Comment: I want to change the text color on user action

Comment: But cells are already drawn on the screen

Comment: Add your code, What did you try?

Comment: nothing yet I was not even sure this was possible. I was thinking i might need to redraw visible cells. Googling it didnot help

Answer (score 1):

Use the following delegate method when your cell will become visible on the screen.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{        
     // call visible on the screen.       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `delegate` methods of [UITableviewCell](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate)

**It is called when the cells became appears to the user.**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     //Set highlighted color here
}
```

**It is called when the cells became disappears to the user.**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    //Set normal color here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a ViewController like this

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var color: UIColor = UIColor.red

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Identifier") as! CustomCell

        cell.labelToChange.textColor = color

        return cell
    }
}
```

On pen click change the `color` to a different color and call `tableView.reloadData()`